# An efficient way to perform rational addition in GNU Octave / Matlab

Tags: matlab, octave, addition, rational-number

Given F, an nx2 matrix of fractions (`[num1, den1; num2, den2; ...]`), how to efficiently compute the fraction that results from their addition? (i.e. `[F(1,1)*F(2,2)*...*F(n,2) + F(1,2)*F(2,1)*F(2,3)*...*F(n,2) + ... , F(1,2)*...*F(n,2)]`). The result doesn't have to be in irreducible form, the point is efficiency (meaning vectorized, not C code).

Comment: For large multiplications your method might exceed the range of 2^52 which will result in inaccurate results.Maybe use `lcm` to get smaller values?

Comment: If `F` is `nx2`, shouldn't that be `F(1,1)*F(2,2)*F(3,2)...*F(n,2) + F(2,1)*F(1,2)*F(3,2)...*F(n,2) + ... 
F(n,1)*F(1,2)*F(2,2)...*F(n-1,2)` instead?

Comment: @Divakar Absolutely. Corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `arrayfun` to apply a function to an array, and `prod` to take the product

```
p = prod(F(:,2));
G = arrayfun(@(x, y) x * p / y, F(:,1), F(:,2));
```

Then your answer is

```
[sum(G), p]
```

or you can do it in a vectorized way as Divakar suggested as

```
p = prod(F(:,2));
G = F(:,1).*(p./F(:,2));
[sum(G), p]
```

I tested both on a 50x2 array with 1000 tries and the results were

```
Elapsed time is 0.594867 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.012170 seconds.
```

So indeed the vectorized way is much faster.

Comment: Or `F(:,1).*(prod(F(:,2),1)./F(:,2))` in a vectorized way.

Comment: @Divakar This new point doesn't have the entity to raise a new question, so I'm giving it a try here: Having an index to F as an m x k matrix I, where F( I( :, j), : ) are the fractions to sum for each column of I. How to compute the sum of all the groups of m fractions in a vectorized way? [ prodfrac(F(I( :, 1), :)), ..., prodfrac(F(I( :, k), :)) ]  (where prodfrac is the solution proposed above by Sbte)

Comment: Something like this? `F1 = reshape(F(l,1), size(l,1), size(l,2));
    F2 = reshape(F(l,2), size(l,1), size(l,2));
    G = F1 ./ F2 * diag(prod(F2));
    [sum(G)', prod(F2)']`. Note that `diag` here is probably slow so you might want to use `spdiags` instead.